# displaying JSON data in a Phoenix Template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to simply display some data in a template. But apparently I'm missing a step.

request with HTTPoison

```
use HTTPoison.Base

@expected_fields ~w(result)   

def process_url(url) do
 "url.json"
end

def process_response_body(body) do
  body
  |> Poison.decode!
  |> Map.take(@expected_fields)
  |> Enum.map(fn({k ,v}) -> {String.to_atom(k), v} end)
end
```

controller

```
 def index(conn, _params) do
  response = ApiTest.get!("").body[:result]
  render conn, "index.html", response: response
 end
```

template

```
<%= @response %>
```

the error is:
 lists in Phoenix.HTML and templates may only contain integers representing bytes, binaries or other lists, got invalid entry

So where do I transform the data to a format that can be displayed in the template?

Comment: Do you have a html template and want to add a json in the body or you want to provide a json response?

Comment: I have a html template and want to add data from the json response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like the `result` key in the response JSON is either a list of contains a list. If you want output for debugging, two common ways are to use `Kernel.inspect` to get a representation like the one in `iex` or `Poison.encode!` to get a JSON representation:

```
<%= inspect(@response) %>
```

or

```
<%= Poison.encode!(@response) %>
```

You might want to wrap the whole thing in `<pre>` tags to get nicely wrapped output in `inspect`:

```
<pre><%= inspect(@response) %></pre>
```

or do that + add `pretty: true` for `Poison.encode!`:

```
<pre><%= Poison.encode!(@response, pretty: true) %></pre>
```